# ¿Cómo traigo información de una BD MYSQL a un proyecto @Vue/Cli?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

Me retorna un status 404 buscando el archivo ajaxfile.php donde tengo los request, habiendo ya instalado axios en mi proyecto, incluso probé agregando el CDN en el index.html pero aun así no funciona.

Les muestro la estructura de las carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, este es mi archivo config.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, el archivo ajaxfile.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, el componente de vue donde hago el post request

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, tengo la instancia de axios debajo de la importacion de reactive from vue, y arriba del export default así:

```
const axios = require('axios')
```

Por ultimo, el error que me muestra en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué no encuentra el archivo, si el enrutamiento está correcto, pienso yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo encuentra porque no estas en la ruta correcta prueba a de dos formar a poner la ruta completa desde el inicio de la aplicación y la otra opción es que en la ruta que te marca no aparece la carpeta src accede directamente a la carpeta database pero primero no esta buscando en src
[image: falta carpeta src]

Revisa la ruta por la que accedes porque intentas acceder directamente a la carpeta database sin pasar por src en todo caso la ruta seria /src/database/...

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero determinar y seguir probando, para saber por qué no me encuentra la ruta que especifico.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo primero trata de validar con npm o yarn.

```
npm i axios
```

desde una terminal o yarn

```
yarn add axios
```

ya con esto no necesitas usar el cdn y sera mas rapida la respuesta.
despues piensa importarlo ejemplo

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
```

o  con vue

```
import axios from "axios";
```

ahora despues de esto podemos realizar una prueba con cualquier api publica hay muchas.

```
  created() {
axios."*METODO*"("*URL*").then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data);
})
```

}

de esta forma puedes validar el axios bueno y si te sigue fallando prueba la BD, y el back siempre prueba la ruta con postman o algo similar.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver tener axios como dependencia de proyecto con el hecho de que tenga un 404 por una ruta a un archivo .php mal ubicado?

Comment: Ese es el dilema, que no entiendo por qué accede directamente desde localhost al archivo, en vez de utilizar el path que le estoy pasando.

Para hacerlo funcionar ya que era para un trabajo de la universidad, tuve que rehacerlo pero esta vez sin utilizar el cliente de vue, simplemente utilizando CDN de axios y vue, y pues escribiendo script de vue y listo. Ahí si me encontraba el archivo.